# TemplateDoesNotExist Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django. Getting this error (TemplateDoesNotExist ) when I refresh the page . 
My code looks like this :
Project name : newsHtml

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('news.urls')),
]
```

I have created another directory called news where files looks like this :
views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
   template= loader.get_template('/home/index.html')
   return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

# def index(request):
#     return HttpResponse("<h1>its working<\h1>")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from. import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
]
```

when i uncomment the HttpResponse i am getting the output .
But not able to find why template is not working .
my directory structure looks like this :

First directory :

```
newsHtml->settings.py,urls.py,wsgi.py
```

Second directory:

```
news->templates/home/index.html,views.py,urls.py
```

I am not able to figure out what is missing . I am using Django 1.11.5.

Comment: Does just 'home/index.html' work? If not, show your template settings. Also note the usual way to do this in the view is to use the `render` shortcut, which replaces both lines of your code.

Comment: 'home/index.html' didn't work.My template setting looks like:`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, why not use the Django shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Your index view should look like so:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "home/index.html")
```

I believe it's because you put a `/` before your `home/index.html`.

Also make sure this is in your settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Furthermore, ensure your application is inside `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: thanks for the response ..added this `from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, "home/index.html")` still the same error .TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
home/index.html
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable: C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.0

Comment: @Husk01inJun I have changed my answer, please look at the edit and ensure that you have that in the settings.

Comment: in settings.py template looks the same, i replaced with your TEMPLATE settings ,still getting the same error

Comment: @Husk01inJun also check your app is inside the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like : `# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'newsHtml',
]`

Comment: @Husk01inJun Change `'newsHtml'` to `'news'`

Comment: holy god , it worked i placed my app name in INSTALLED_APPS instead of project name .thanks a ton